# unable to find whois library

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

I am trying "whois" with python.

I installed whois for python using following code (OS:- CentOS 7)

```
pip install python-whois
```

when I run following three commands at python console it works

```
import whois
w = whois.whois('www.google.com')
print w
```

But when same three lines I save in file whois.py and run code with command
python whois.py

It gives following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "whois.py", line 1, in <module>
    import whois
  File "/home/sysadmin/pythonPractice/whois.py", line 2, in <module>
    w = whois.whois('www.google.com')
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1):

this issue is because your filename is whois.py and when you try to call the library whois it gets overwritten so, you should name your file from whois.py to something else.

Comment: I tried it. I gave name like m.py to file and still same error.

Comment: try filename.py and copy the same code in that. I tried it worked for me and I was able to reproduce your error with the steps you mentioned.

Comment: which python are you using?\

Comment: Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug  4 2017, 00:39:18) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>

Comment: i think python-whois does not support python2

Comment: try to run filename.py with python3 filename.py